# c# custom exceptions is unhandled

Tags: c#, exception

Class assignment is to create your own custom exception (MyEmptyStringException) in this case.

Here is what I have:

```
class Program
    {
        public class MyEmptyStringException : Exception
        {
          public MyEmptyStringException(string message) : base(message) { }
        }

        public class MyOutOfRangeException : Exception
        {
            public MyOutOfRangeException(string message) : base(message) { }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string testStr;
            byte testByte;
            bool validValue = false;

            Student myStudent = new Student();

            do
            {//start do loop

                Console.WriteLine("Enter student's first name");

                try
                {
                    testStr = (Console.ReadLine());

                    if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(testStr)))
                    {
                        throw new MyEmptyStringException("Answer was blank");
                        // Console.WriteLine("String is empty");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        validValue = true;
                    } //end if
                }
                catch (FormatException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + e.Message + "Format Exception!\n");
                }
                catch (OverflowException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + e.Message + "Overflow Exception\n");
                }

             } while (!validValue);
            myStudent.firstName = Console.ReadLine();
```

For me it errors out here:

```
throw new MyEmptyStringException("Answer was blank");
```

with the error message: MyEmptyStringException was unhandled. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're only catching `FormatException` and `OverflowException`. Your exception isn't either of those things, so it goes unhandled. Incidentally, I would recommend against throwing an exception here: an empty value may not be a valid user input, but it is a valid result of `Console.ReadLine()`, and thus not really an exception.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean about the `Console.ReadLine()` . Is there another way in C# to assign variables from user input without using `Console.ReadLine()` ?

Answer (score 2):

Catch your custom exceptions:

MyEmptyStringException and MyOutOfRangeException

Eg:

```
try
 {

 }
 catch (MyEmptyStringException mese)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(mese.Message);
 }
 catch (MyOutOfRangeException moofre)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(moofre.Message);
 }
```

Comment: Awesome. That makes sense now.

The example the teacher used used that if statement to test if a byte was 5>= && <=20.